# I have an address mms://www.somesite.com/abcd but can't find a way to open in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, media-player

Using the newest and most awesome Windows Media Player on Windows 7, I have an address mms://www.somesite.com/abcd but can't figure out how to open it...

It must be a profound software system.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows Media Player, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, paste the URL there and click Open.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Media Player you can access the normal menu system by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or by right-clicking on the top bar, where the Back and Forward buttons are, with the mouse.  Once in the menus, go to the "File" menu and select "Open URL..."   You can then paste the URL in the window to play it.

Comment: Is this the only product where the "File -> Open" are all hidden and it takes Alt or Right click on the Back or Forward to open up the Menu?  I have Office 2003 and the menu was harder to find already.  Now it is even harder.  I wonder what Office 2007 or 2010 is like.  WordPad's menu on Win 7 is not hidden so deeply.